# Oneliner for failing a bash command if its status is within a certain range

Tags: bash, travis-ci, yarnpkg

Is there a nice way of calling a command in bash and failing if its return code was within a certain range/met a certain condition?

My use-case:

I have CI set up on Travis, and want to add a `yarn audit` check to my test script for HIGH or CRITICAL vulnerabilities. When calling [yarn audit](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/audit/), the returned status code is a bitmask of vulnerability levels, so that for example if you have moderate (4) and critical (16) levels, you get 20 back. And I want to fail my script if there are at least any high alerts, so if status >= 8.

Travis is setup so that a list of commands are run in sequence, aborting when there's a non-zero status code, so basically a `set -e` setup I guess.

My current attempt at this is the following:

```
yarn audit || (mask=$? && [ $mask -lt 8 ])
```

This works, but is there a more nice & tidy approach than this? I mean, to me it doesn't exactly scream "run this command and fail if the status code was >=8" For example, is there a way of avoiding the `$?` syntax when all you need to do is condition the status code once? I'm thinking along the lines of a single bracket expression such as `[ $(yarn audit) -lt 8]`, which obviously isn't what I want since `$(yarn audit)` return the output of the command, not the status code, but just to get what I'm aiming for.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand right, the script has `set -e` set, but you only want to exit if the status from `yarn audit` is 8 or more, right? If so, you can simplify what you have slightly by skipping the `mask` variable:

```
yarn audit || [ $? -lt 8 ]
```

The main drawback is that you can't do anything else with `yarn`'s status, because it gets immediately replaced by the status from the `[ ]` test. (BTW, if you did want to save it for later, you'd have to use `{ ;}` instead of `( )`, to avoid putting that code in a subshell).

Now, I tend not to trust `set -e` to do the right thing, because its idea of when it's appropriate to exit isn't always what you expect or want (see [BashFAQ #105: "Why doesn't `set -e` (or `set -o errexit`, or `trap ERR`) do what I expected?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)). I prefer explicit `exit` commands, something like this:

```
yarn audit || [ $? -lt 8 ] || {
    echo "Audit failed" >&2
    exit 1
}
```

Or, a little clumsy but clearer in intent:

```
yarn audit || if [ $? -ge 8 ]; then
    echo "Audit failed" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Thanks. One problem is that I'm not sure how Travis handles multiline commands such as this, as the commands are single strings in a YAML array, but the code it is indeed much clearer. Maybe the best option is to wrap this in a `audit.sh` script and just invoke `- ./audit.sh` from Travis.

Comment: @JHH I'm not familiar with Travis, but it sounds like wrapping it in a script might be the cleanest option.